# Nodejs RPM rebuild error with centos 6.8

Tags: node.js, rpm, rpmbuild, centos6.5

I'm trying to rebuild nodejs 4.2.3 rpm and when running rpm build getting following error.

```
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:184: error: expected initializer before '<' token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:202: error: template declaration of 'LockGuard final'
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:203: error: expected primary-expression before 'public'
```

Any idea what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/issues/74

Comment: What does `gcc -v` show?

Comment: gcc 4.4.7-17
g++ 4.4.7-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3347

Updated gcc & g++ accroding to the (https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/e3bc5cfacc2dc67eca8b ) & now it's working fine.